# purpose of "Catalog Product Rule" and "Catalog Rule Product"

Tags: magento2, indexing, catalog-rules

What exactly is the purpose of the "Catalog Product Rule" and "Catalog Rule Product" indexes?

Which functionalities do they cover?

I am just wondering, because there are often a lot of entries in the backlog of the indexer and we are not using any **product rules** within Magento **that I know of**.

Thus I am wondering if I can disable those indexes to make the `indexer_update_all_views` cron job a little faster.

### Update --------------

As answered by Rakesh Donga, "Catalog Product Rule" are the [Cart Price Rules](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/marketing/price-rules-cart.html) and "Catalog Rule Product" are the [Catalog Price Rules](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/marketing/price-rules-catalog.html) (awful naming though ;)).

Since we have not defined any such rules in our shop: why are there still so many entries to be indexed for the "Catalog Product Rule" index? Are there base rules that Magento always accounts for?

Answer (score 3):

Both "Catalog Product Rule" (catalogrule_product) and "Catalog Rule Product" (catalogrule_rule) indexers belongs to [Catalog Price Rule](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/marketing/price-rules-catalog.html) functionality.

Table `catalogrule_product_cl` ("Catalog Product Rule" indexer change log table) is populated even You don't have defined any "Catalog Price Rule". This is because of mview implementation. In file `vendor/magento/module-catalog-rule/etc/mview.xml` You can see that `catalogrule_product` subscribes tables like `catalog_product_entity`, `catalog_product_entity_datetime` etc. This means that [trigger](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers/) is created in database that will add values to table `catalogrule_product_cl` if You change any value in table that is subscribed. This functionality works on database level. You can try it by manually change values in table `catalog_product_entity_decimal`. You will see that entries are added to `catalogrule_product_cl` table. After use command `bin/magento indexer:status` You can see that entries number in backlog of "Catalog Product Rule" indexer is increasing. I would like to mention that in backlog You see number of unique entity_id elements occuring in table `catalogrule_product_cl` from version_id defined in row `catalogrule_product` in table `mview_state` to last element.

Answer (score 2):

> **Catalog Product Rule :** This indexer creates and updates the created
>   Shopping cart price rule set 
>  **Catalog Rule Product:** This indexer
>   creates and updates the created catalog price rule set

Comment: Hm, that does not really explain the difference though. What is a "shopping cart price rule set" and what is a "catalog price rule set"? // edit: ah found the information now, I'll update my question accordingly

Answer (score 2):

Please find below my explanation for these 2.

catalogrule_rule - Catalog Product Rule (The reindex all the catalog rule "conditions", as soon as you update any condition like 10% discount or something, this needs to re-run)

catalogrule_product - Catalog Rule Product (If you update the product on which catalog rule will be applied)

I hope this helps.

Comment: The explanation is good. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Yes, it answers the original question. It does not explain though, why there are indexing entries even though we have no rules defined whatsoever.